# Understanding assumptions of equivalence of random effects variances; what to do when violated?

Tags: mixed-model, variance, heteroscedasticity, model-based-clustering

The random effects model is stated as:

$Y_{ij} = \mu + \tau_i+\epsilon_{ij}$

Where,

$\tau_i \overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, \sigma^2_{\mu} ) \\ $
$\epsilon_{ij} \overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 )$

Further, we know the variance decomposes into components:

$ \sigma^2_{Y} = V (\mu_i + \epsilon_{ij}) = \sigma_{\mu}^{2}+\sigma_{\epsilon}^2 $

My question is whether I understand correctly that there is an assumption of equal within-group variances. The model setup above seems to assume there is.

For example, if we are sampling raters who have scored some data or some system function, we assume a between-rater variance of $ \sigma^2_{\mu} $ and some consistent within-rater variance $ \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 $

I can see why this would be useful to assume from an efficiency standpoint. Nonetheless, it is a very strong assumption, as I see it. Conceivably, if you think your different effects variances within are not the same, you need to use some other model or not group them together.

For example, let's assume one rater is extremely consistent; another rater is wildly inconsistent. In the random effects model, this seems to all just get absorbed into the error term but not modeled directly; the ICC is global.

What do you typically do in that case?